# Substitute string that contains a backslash

Tags: macros, strings, xstring

I need to create a function that will transform a string such as:

```
Hello\textbackslash{}Bye
```

into this:

```
Hello \\ Bye
```

I have tried using `StrSubstitute` (from the `xstring` package) without success.  I have attempted things along these lines:

```
\newcommand{\TRANSFORM}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{\textbackslash{}}{ \noexpand\\ }}

\TRANSFORM{Hello\textbackslash{}Bye}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just temporarily redefine the meaning of `\textbackslash`, letting it to `\\`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\TRANSFORM}[1]{{\let\textbackslash\\#1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

Hello\textbackslash{}Bye

\TRANSFORM{Hello\textbackslash{}Bye}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `\noexpandarg` mode of `xstring`, so it won't try expanding its arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

%\noexpandarg % set \noexpandarg globally

\newcommand{\TRANSFORM}[1]{%
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg % set \noexpandarg locally
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{\textbackslash{}}{\\}%
  \restoreexpandmode % restore the previous mode
}

\begin{document}

\TRANSFORM{Hello\textbackslash{}Bye}

\end{document}
```

Depending on your usage of `xstring`, you might also set `\noexpandarg` globally (by commenting/uncommenting the relevant lines).

Of course, in this case, redefining a macro is better:

```
\newcommand\TRANSFORM[1]{{% open a group
   \renewcommand{\textbackslash}[1]{\\}%
   #1%
}}
```

Why `\renewcommand` and not `\let`? Because this redefinition also swallows `{}`.